# mysql service fails to start/hangs up - timeout (Ubuntu, MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, service, timeout, mariadb, autostart

I set up my first Ubuntu Server with Ubuntu 16.04, nginx, php7.0, MariaDB, nextcloud and external DynDNS using this tutorial here: [Install Nextcloud 9 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Everything worked fine but since I restarted the server the next day, nextcloud just shows me a blank page. After clicking through all logs of nginx, MariaDB and nextcloud, I found out that the mysql service just doesn't start. So run `service mysql start` and everything worked fine again (calling nextcloud from server as well as other workstations). I just wondered that the terminal didn't "close" the line. Like it was still working on the command. After about 5 minutes, the line "closes" and the following message appears:

> "Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See
>   "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Then the clients again just get a blank page in nextcloud. When I run the command and close the terminal immediately, clients get the access as well but still loses it after 5 minutes.

I tried backing up the nextcloud, sql and run `apt-get purge --auto-remove mariadb-server`. Then again run the MariaDB installation steps out of the tutorial with importing the backup sql instead of creating a new one. Didn't change everything.

Next try was `update-rc.d mysql defaults` and `update-rc.d mysql enable`. But after a restart just the blank page again. Access is only possible for 5 minutes by starting the service manual.

I also tried the [BUM - BootUpManager](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SysVinit/#BUM-Boot-Up-Manager) but the service seems to be enabled. I saw you can start services out oft it manually as well. So tried it with mysql and surprise: nextcloud available for 5 minutes while BUM just hangs up.

I found mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/starting-and-stopping-mariadb-automatically/ as well but tried nothing of it because it seems like there is something else really wrong.

`root@s1:~# systemctl status mariadb.service`:

```
\u25cf mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           \u2514\u2500migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Di 2016-12-06 14:52:51 CET; 55s ago
  Process: 3565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WS
  Process: 3415 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR
  Process: 3409 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START
  Process: 3405 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/ru
 Main PID: 3565 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dez 06 14:52:48 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:48 3067387712 [Note] /usr/sbin
Dez 06 14:52:48 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:48 3067387712 [Note] Event Sch
Dez 06 14:52:48 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:48 2147785536 [Note] InnoDB: F
Dez 06 14:52:48 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:48 3067387712 [Note] InnoDB: S
Dez 06 14:52:49 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:49 3067387712 [Note] InnoDB: W
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:50 3067387712 [Note] InnoDB: S
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:50 3067387712 [Note] /usr/sbin
Dez 06 14:52:51 s1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Dez 06 14:52:51 s1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dez 06 14:52:51 s1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

`root@s1:~# journalctl -xe`:

```
Dez 06 14:52:48 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:48 3067387712 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Dez 06 14:52:48 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:48 2147785536 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Dez 06 14:52:48 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:48 3067387712 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Dez 06 14:52:49 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:49 3067387712 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer po
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:50 3067387712 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 111890806
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 mysqld[3565]: 2016-12-06 14:52:50 3067387712 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 audit[3648]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profi
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1481032370.973:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - 
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 audit[3565]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profi
Dez 06 14:52:50 s1 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1481032370.973:30): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - 
Dez 06 14:52:51 s1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dez 06 14:52:51 s1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dez 06 14:52:51 s1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dez 06 14:54:54 s1 x11vnc[2665]: 06/12/2016 14:54:54 cursor_noshape_updates_clients: 1
Dez 06 14:55:16 s1 ntpd[1244]: 46.4.1.155 local addr 192.168.178.50 -> <null>
Dez 06 14:57:30 s1 ntpd[1244]: 89.238.66.98 local addr 192.168.178.50 -> <null>
```

Content in /ect/init.d (if useful):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mysql
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $named $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $named $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
# Description:       Controls the main MariaDB database server daemon "mysqld"
#                    and its wrapper script "mysqld_safe".
### END INIT INFO
#
set -e
set -u
${DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG:+ set -v -x}

test -x /usr/sbin/mysqld || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

SELF=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd -P)/$(basename $0)
CONF=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"

# priority can be overriden and "-s" adds output to stderr
ERR_LOGGER="logger -p daemon.err -t /etc/init.d/mysql -i"

# Safeguard (relative paths, core dumps..)
cd /
umask 077

# mysqladmin likes to read /root/.my.cnf. This is usually not what I want
# as many admins e.g. only store a password without a username there and
# so break my scripts.
export HOME=/etc/mysql/

# Source default config file.
[ -r /etc/default/mariadb ] && . /etc/default/mariadb

## Fetch a particular option from mysql's invocation.
#
# Usage: void mysqld_get_param option
mysqld_get_param() {
    /usr/sbin/mysqld --print-defaults \
        | tr " " "\n" \
        | grep -- "--$1" \
        | tail -n 1 \
        | cut -d= -f2
}

## Do some sanity checks before even trying to start mysqld.
sanity_checks() {
  # check for config file
  if [ ! -r /etc/mysql/my.cnf ]; then
    log_warning_msg "$0: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz"
    echo                "WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz" | $ERR_LOGGER
  fi

  # check for diskspace shortage
  datadir=`mysqld_get_param datadir`
  if LC_ALL=C BLOCKSIZE= df --portability $datadir/. | tail -n 1 | awk '{ exit ($4>4096) }'; then
    log_failure_msg "$0: ERROR: The partition with $datadir is too full!"
    echo                "ERROR: The partition with $datadir is too full!" | $ERR_LOGGER
    exit 1
  fi
}

## Checks if there is a server running and if so if it is accessible.
#
# check_alive insists on a pingable server
# check_dead also fails if there is a lost mysqld in the process list
#
# Usage: boolean mysqld_status [check_alive|check_dead] [warn|nowarn]
mysqld_status () {
    ping_output=`$MYADMIN ping 2>&1`; ping_alive=$(( ! $? ))

    ps_alive=0
    pidfile=`mysqld_get_param pid-file`
    if [ -f "$pidfile" ] && ps `cat $pidfile` >/dev/null 2>&1; then ps_alive=1; fi

    if [ "$1" = "check_alive"  -a  $ping_alive = 1 ] ||
       [ "$1" = "check_dead"   -a  $ping_alive = 0  -a  $ps_alive = 0 ]; then
    return 0 # EXIT_SUCCESS
    else
    if [ "$2" = "warn" ]; then
        echo -e "$ps_alive processes alive and '$MYADMIN ping' resulted in\n$ping_output\n" | $ERR_LOGGER -p daemon.debug
    fi
    return 1 # EXIT_FAILURE
    fi
}

#
# main()
#

case "${1:-''}" in
  'start')
    sanity_checks;
    # Start daemon
    log_daemon_msg "Starting MariaDB database server" "mysqld"
    if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
       log_progress_msg "already running"
       log_end_msg 0
    else
        # Could be removed during boot
        test -e /var/run/mysqld || install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld

        # Start MariaDB! 
        /usr/bin/mysqld_safe "${@:2}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &

        # 6s was reported in #352070 to be too little
        for i in $(seq 1 "${MYSQLD_STARTUP_TIMEOUT:-60}"); do
                sleep 1
            if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn ; then break; fi
        log_progress_msg "."
        done
        if mysqld_status check_alive warn; then
                log_end_msg 0
            # Now start mysqlcheck or whatever the admin wants.
            output=$(/etc/mysql/debian-start)
        [ -n "$output" ] && log_action_msg "$output"
        else
            log_end_msg 1
        log_failure_msg "Please take a look at the syslog"
        fi
    fi
    ;;

  'stop')
    # * As a passwordless mysqladmin (e.g. via ~/.my.cnf) must be possible
    # at least for cron, we can rely on it here, too. (although we have 
    # to specify it explicit as e.g. sudo environments points to the normal
    # users home and not /root)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping MariaDB database server" "mysqld"
    if ! mysqld_status check_dead nowarn; then
      set +e
      shutdown_out=`$MYADMIN shutdown 2>&1`; r=$?
      set -e
      if [ "$r" -ne 0 ]; then
        log_end_msg 1
        [ "$VERBOSE" != "no" ] && log_failure_msg "Error: $shutdown_out"
        log_daemon_msg "Killing MariaDB database server by signal" "mysqld"
        killall -15 mysqld
            server_down=
        for i in `seq 1 600`; do
              sleep 1
              if mysqld_status check_dead nowarn; then server_down=1; break; fi
            done
          if test -z "$server_down"; then killall -9 mysqld; fi
      fi
        fi

        if ! mysqld_status check_dead warn; then
      log_end_msg 1
      log_failure_msg "Please stop MariaDB manually and read /usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.1/README.Debian.gz!"
      exit -1
    else
      log_end_msg 0
        fi
    ;;

  'restart')
    set +e; $SELF stop; set -e
    $SELF start 
    ;;

  'reload'|'force-reload')
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading MariaDB database server" "mysqld"
    $MYADMIN reload
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;

  'status')
    if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
      log_action_msg "$($MYADMIN version)"
    else
      log_action_msg "MariaDB is stopped."
      exit 3
    fi
    ;;

  'bootstrap')
    # Bootstrap the cluster, start the first node
    # that initiates the cluster
    log_daemon_msg "Bootstrapping the cluster" "mysqld"
    $SELF start "${@:2}" --wsrep-new-cluster
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: $SELF start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|bootstrap"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Unfortunately, Google can't help me. I tried to explain as much as I can maybe this helps you in helping me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Save yourself sometime and scroll [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023297/5403449)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long question for nothing... Never heard of AppArmor but it was the reasen. The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750604/why-does-mariadb-keep-dying-how-do-i-stop-it/753280#753280) fixed it. Don't care about apparmor's ERROR the profile wouldn't exist.

> `sudo aa-status` shows you what apparmor is doing; what actually has an
>   enforced policy, versus what's just set to complain.
>
> `sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils` adds a few commands that make the
>   apparmor profiles easier to deal with, such as...
>
> `sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld` turns the profile from "enforce" to
>   complain. (aa-enforce turns it back.)
>
> Once that's done, `sudo service apparmor reload` restarts apparmor, and
>   voila... `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` works, and the server stays up.

Answer (score 134):

In case you are bitten by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.1/+bug/1806263), the solution is given as a suggestion in the bug report (all of these have to be done as root, so either with `sudo -i` as a zeroth command or with `sudo` prefixed):

1. `echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" > /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` (the second part with sudo is `... | sudo tee /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, thank you [@dvlcube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1360042/dvlcube))
2. `apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`
3. `systemctl restart mariadb`

### Background

If you previously had MySQL installed, it activated an AppArmor profile which is incompatible with MariaDB.  `apt-get remove --purge` only removes the profile, but does not deactivate/unload it.  Only manually unloading it lets MariaDB work unhindered by AppArmor.

Comment: What a load of shit, why is the /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld file not shipped with mariadb if apparmor is going to be used by default?!

Comment: Just needs "sudo su" ubuntu 18.10

Comment: @Josh Do you mean that you need to be root for these commands? Yes, of course.  But I personally prefer `sudo -i` ;-)

Comment: Running `aa-remove-unknown` will remove the lingering profile.

Comment: Also, later versions of MariaDB in Ububtu 18.04 ships with `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` (You still need to run `aa-remove-unknown` though)

Comment: For step 1, if you're using sudo, change to: 
`echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" | sudo tee /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

Comment: @dvlcube Thank you, I added that.

Answer (score 39):

This last option worked for me (from quazgar).  I have Ubuntu 18.10 installed with MariaDB 10.3.13:

```
$ echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" > /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
$ apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
$ systemctl restart mariadb
```

I had to use "sudo su" for it to work though.

Comment: Subsequently my Mariadb died again.  This time I had to also follow the solution proposed by Dave Hindle above.  Then I reinstalled Mariadb using "Synaptic Package Manager".  After that, "sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service" worked.

Comment: Worked fine for me

Answer (score 11):

Moving mysqld to "complain" group was not enough in my case (MariaDB 10.1.21 running on Ubuntu 16.04).
I had to fully disable apparmor for mysqld:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/ 
sudo service apparmor reload
sudo service mysql restart
```

Now everything works fine.

Comment: This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 7):

FYI:

In my case neither the solution of Vincent or Lw Bi worked exactly, I needed some further actions.

Disabling the profile through placing a link in `/etc/apparmor.d/disable/` simply didn't work, I don't know why.

On the other hand, setting MySQL to complain mode didn't work either immediately.

```
:~$ sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Setting `/usr/sbin/mysqld` to complain mode.

```
ERROR: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld contains no profile
```

I needed to add the lines:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld {
}
```

to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, and then I could set it to complain mode successfully.

Comment: This worked. I created it like `/usr/sbin/mysqld {}` (no newline) and it throwed "... contains no profile". So newline is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that since 10.1.10, MariaDB uses systemd to start the service. If you have tried MYSQLD_STARTUP_TIMEOUT and it has not worked, you are probably using this or a later version. The /etc/init.d/mysql script is no longer used, so MYSQLD_STARTUP_TIMEOUT has no effect.

You need to find your mariadb.service file. In our case, it did not contain a timeout so the MariaDB default was being used. Just add:

TimeoutStartSec = 0

In the [Service] section, and it will never time out.

It would be a good idea to create your own config file containing this so it doesn't get overwritten by later re-installs.

On ubuntu 18.04, you will fine this file in

/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service

Put your own file in

/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d

Remember to run systemctl daemon-reload after adding the timeout somewhere (and maybe check /var/log/syslog to see if the reload was successful), otherwise your time out will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. You need to set appropriate timeout in the systemd config for mariadb service. Below solved same for me. for ex. When system requires SST it may take long time for mariadb service to come up causing the timeout in systemd.

If you are using systemd 228 or older, then you can execute the following to set an infinite timeout.

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/timeoutsec.conf <<EOF
[Service]

TimeoutStartSec=0
TimeoutStopSec=0
EOF
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

For other options please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issu. It was a certificate file missing that was linked to in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
This was missing:
/etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem

Had to copy it from another node by ctrl+c into nano. Got permission error when copy with scp.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

> The correction didn't work for me.
>
> $ sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld Setting /usr/sbin/mysqld to
>   complain mode.
>
> ERROR: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld contains no profile So I
>   disabled the profile (with aa-disable which seems to be equivalent to
>   plutocrat's solution)
>
> $ sudo aa-disable /usr/sbin/mysqld Disabling /usr/sbin/mysqld. I
>   disabled mysqld-akonadi and mysqld-digikam as well.
>
> An apparmor reload was not enough, so I had to reboot and mariadb
>   started perfectly well.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/964928/106100

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to run the following:

```
sudo killall mysqld
```

If you are still experiencing this issue, run the command `ps -aux | grep 'mysql'`. if anything shows up, just kill it as well.

Finally run:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```