# mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

Since today morning I have a problem with the mariadb.service running on Ubuntu 18.04 with Plesk. It stopped and I can't restart it again.

```
service mysqld start
Job for mariadb.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.2.27 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Thu 2019-10-24 21:14:25 CEST; 3s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 26703 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26699 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26932 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
  Process: 26717 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (co
  Process: 26715 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26714 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26932 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Okt 24 18:21:40 XXXXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Okt 24 18:21:40 XXXXX systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.27 database server.
Okt 24 18:21:45 XXXXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Okt 24 18:21:45 XXXXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1251.
Okt 24 18:21:45 XXXXX systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.2.27 database server.
Okt 24 18:21:45 XXXXX systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.2.27 database server...
Okt 24 18:21:46 XXXXX mysqld[22593]: 2019-10-24 18:21:46 140599485605184 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.2.27-MariaDB-1:10.2.27+maria~bionic) starting as process 22593 ...
Okt 24 18:21:47 XXXXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Okt 24 18:21:47 XXXXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Okt 24 18:21:47 XXXXX systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.2.27 database server.
```

I already tried the following things:

- server restart
- [mysql service fails to start/hangs up - timeout (Ubuntu, MariaDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997257/mysql-service-fails-to-start-hangs-up-timeout-ubuntu-mariadb)
- https://help.univention.com/t/problem-mysql-server-does-not-start-any-more/10010

How can I get mariadb running again?

Answer (score 3):

You have to look at mysqld logs to find a reason, in my case it was /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log file. Search for the last string containing [ERROR] [FATAL] keywords and read/google error messages above to it.

Comment: it depends on what you read in mysqld.log
in my case, I've seen 
[ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of tablespace innodb_system page [...]. You may have to recover from a backup.
...
[ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Aborting because of a corrupt database page.
and I had to start mysql in innodb recovery mode, as written https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/

Answer (score 0):

I saw same error and it appeared after i moved mysql data to a smaller volume but forgot to fix it,s permissions. After giving mysql user proper permissions it started working fine.

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql/
```

OS: Ubuntu 18 and Mariadb 10.2.4