# How to run Maria DB for long time in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, mariadb-10.4

I wrote systemctl start mariadb
**it shows:**

> Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
>   See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

For few minutes, /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock exist, and I can see my DB in phpmyadmin,
But again, /var/run/mysqld/  becomes empty
when I run systemctl status mariadb.service
it shows:

● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.10 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2019-11-24 12:41:59 IST; 13s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 3555 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3414 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && syste
  Process: 3412 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3411 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3555 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 24 12:41:57 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:57 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Nov 24 12:41:57 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Nov 24 12:41:57 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Nov 24 12:41:57 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffe
Nov 24 12:41:57 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 191124 12:41:57
Nov 24 12:41:59 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 139944; t
Nov 24 12:41:59 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Nov 24 12:41:59 administrator-Vostro-3480 mysqld[3555]: 2019-11-24 12:41:59 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Nov 24 12:41:59 administrator-Vostro-3480 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 24 12:41:59 administrator-Vostro-3480 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.4.10 database server.
lines 1-23/23 (END)

**How to increase timelimit ??**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql service fails to start/hangs up - timeout (Ubuntu, MariaDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997257/mysql-service-fails-to-start-hangs-up-timeout-ubuntu-mariadb)

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997257/mysql-service-fails-to-start-hangs-up-timeout-ubuntu-mariadb

Comment: What do the logs show?  Likely an error starting.

Comment: please post **systemctl status mariadb.service** and separatly **journalctl -xe** they will tell us what happens.

Comment: I posted , please check