# MariaDB automatically shutting down after sometime

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

Hi instaled maria db 10 on ubuntu 20 and my db keeps getting shuting down after sometime and giving below error message:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Below are my server logs
[image: Error Logs]

I have tried almost every step and possible answer availabe on stackoverflow but no luck. Please avaoid putting answers like restart service, server etc.

I stated the service but its stuck. If I press ctrl + c then it works. Is it normal?[image: starting service]

Comment: Curious to the `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('` before tailing the log? ... is there some sort of shell script in play?

Comment: @PaulT. no I checked  no script is in play

Comment: I checked the mysqld.sock file. It keeps on getting deleted after 5-6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you have mysql previously installed and you uninstall it then also it won't remove the AppArmour profile. It is an existing bug.

[Solution which worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997257/mysql-service-fails-to-start-hangs-up-timeout-ubuntu-mariadb)

[Bug Description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.1/+bug/1806263)